# Como evitar loop al intentar autocompletar input de tipo select usando setInterval

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente codigo, la idea es que usando interval seleccione un valor en un select y luego asigne un valor a otro select. Pero el evento change que debo usar esta ocasionando que la pagina se refresque y quede en loop. Alguna sugerencia?

```js
var interval = setInterval(doStuff, 3000); // 2000 ms = start after 2sec 

function doStuff() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(null, 
    function(result) {
       var item = JSON.parse(result.key);
       var reg = document.getElementById('form1:layoutPanel1:layoutPanel2:regional_list');
       reg.value = item.regional;
       reg.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

       var ciudad = document.getElementById('form1:layoutPanel1:layoutPanel2:ciudad_list');
       ciudad.value = item.ciudad;


  });
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: no iría mejor un timeout ?

Comment: me ocurre exactamente lo mismo usando time out, interval ,promises, lo que sea.. es mas cuestion de evitar que el refresh que provoca el event haga que la funcion siga ejecutandose..

Comment: fijate si esta forma de disparar el evento te sirve https://stackoverflow.com/a/11394087/1423096

Comment: Sigue el mismo loop :(

Comment: no habrá algún otro evento colgado del onchange?

Comment: el primer select tiene ciertos valores, el segundo select va a cargarse de valores que dependen de lo que yo escogi en el primero. No tengo acceso a nada de ese codigo porque la pagina no es mia. Lo que yo estoy corriendo sobre ella es una extension de chrome.

Comment: si se nota q es una extensión, pero igualmente yo probaría abrir la página sin extensiones  inspeccionar el select  y ver la pestaña "event listeners"

Answer (score 0):

Cogiendo la funcion "debounce" de underscore se puede utilizar de la forma siguiente:

```
function debounce(fn, wait, inmediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!inmediate) fn.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = inmediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) fn.apply(context, args);
   };
};
```

Y luego la invocas como necesites:

```
var waitFn = debounce(function() {
    /* Lógica de la función */
}, 1000); //tiempo en ms
```

Esta función puedes almacenarla en tu fichero JS, no necesitas descargarte la librería entera para poderla ejecutar.

introducir el código aquí

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado.